# Coordinate transformations

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have two scalar functions of $x$ and $y$ that I can define:

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2\qquad
\text{and}\qquad
g(x,y)=x^2 + \sin^2(x) y^2.$$

Is it true that there is literally no coordinate change that will take one to the other?

Comment: Doesn’t $(x\rightarrow x, y\rightarrow y\sin{x})$ take $f$ to $g$?

Comment: @G.Smith I think that the domain and range of function would somewhat change when you will switch from y to ysinx. So we must check the range of each function.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Unique: good point but in the case the domain and range of both $f$ and $g$ are unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, note that $$\mathrm{d}f\wedge\mathrm{d}g ~=~ h(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y,$$ where $$h(x,y)~:=~ 2y\{2x(\sin^2(x)-1)-y^2\sin(2x) \} ~=~ -4y\cos(x)\{x \cos(x)+y^2\sin(x) \}.$$ The pair $(f,g)$ are by definition **functionally independent** within the set $$\Omega~:=~\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2| h(x,y)\neq 0\}.$$ By the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) the pair $(f,g)$ constitutes local coordinates in sufficiently small neighborhoods of $\Omega$.